# Who were the portrayed people over Bilbo's fireplace?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-hobbit

Towards the end of the last Hobbit movie, The Battle of the Five Armies, when Bilbo returned to Bag End, he fixed some pictures of two people that were over his fireplace.

[image]

Who were these two people?

Comment: I assumed they were his parents, although I don't recall any evidence (either movie dialogue or in the original writings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**We don't know**

There is only one definite confirmation of anything Bilbo hung over his fireplace in the books, and that's in the Prologue to Lord of the Rings:

> His sword, Sting, Bilbo hung over his fireplace...

Likewise there's no mention of pictures, portraits, paintings or parents, and nothing relevant about Bungo or Belladonna.  However, it does seem reasonable to assume that they're his parents (http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Bungo_Baggins suggests that they are).

The movies of course say nothing (there may be something on the Extended Edition BoFA commentary when that gets released, so we might find out next year).

Comment: I seem to remember these from the LotR movies too, so a listen to the commentaries of those may reveal more.  Also, according to some internet sources, they're portraits of Peter Jackson and Fran Walsh, so they may be just an Easter Egg.

Comment: You are right. Just watched the first quarter of The Fellowship for the sake of finding the portraits (and because it's awesome, of course): http://cl.ly/image/3a261b2O2b2T

Comment: It has just been confirmed that the hobbit depicted in the portrait is indeed Sir Peter Jackson: http://www.theonering.net/torwp/2015/01/03/96262-peter-jacksons-long-goodbye-to-middle-earth-and-his-five-armies-cameo/

Comment: @AlfredoHernández - Excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

### These are Bilbo's parents Bungo Baggins and Belladonna Took. They are played by Peter Jackson and Fran Walsh

This is discussed in the director's commentary for the film.

> **Philippa Boyens:**  I wonder if they made the link here.
> **Peter Jackson:** Yes, everyone wondered where my cameo was in this film and there it is, there we go, I've said it.
> **Philippa Boyens:** Fran Walsh and Peter Jackson
> **Peter Jackson:** Yes, I've always been there, I've always been up on the mantlepiece, and everyone was saying, "but you didn't do a cameo, where's your cameo", and I said "It's there. It's there. It's hiding in plain sight".
> **Philippa Boyens:** It's Bilbo's parents. Just entirely appropriate, don't you think?
> **Peter Jackson:** So what's my name if I'm his father?
> **Philippa Boyens:** Oh god, um, Bungo?
> Bungo?
> **Philippa Boyens:** Yeah, Bungo, and that's uh Belladonna. Belladonna which is perfect for Fran.
> **Peter Jackson:** Can I have a better name than Bungo?
> **Philippa Boyens:** No sorry, you're Bungo. You're now for everybody known as Bungo.
> **Peter Jackson:** Oh dear, oh dear. I wonder if I get credited as Bungo in the credits. I don't think I do.
> **Philippa Boyens:** I think you should complain.
> **Peter Jackson:** Or we should maybe get a petition happening about that, ay?
> **Philippa Boyens:** Okay.
> <sub>*The Battle of the Five Armies* - Director's Commentary [2:29:02-2:29:55]</sub>

These pictures were not new, and both appeared in several scenes of The Fellowship of the Ring.

[image]

It's also worth mentioning that one of the major themes of *The Hobbit* (or at least of the book), is Bilbo being the child of both of his parents, and him resonating his respectable "Baggins" side with his adventurous "Took" side. So ending on a picture of his parents in thematically appropriate.

Comment: It's a shame they appear to be oil paintings, and not actual [cameos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameo_(carving)) ;)